# Operating on all files/classes in a directory

Tags: php, phpunit

I am just starting with PHPunit so not sure if I'm missing something basic but I'd like to have a test case:

- scan a particular source directory,
- find all files with .PHP extension,
- then attempt to instantiate each of the classes represented by these files
- test that each class returns the right properties from particular call (all classes in this directory are subtypes of a common base class)

Make sense? The setup code would look like this:

```
protected function setUp() {
    $this->documentFiles = glob('*.php');
    $this->documentClasses = array_map(function($file) {
         return substr($file,0,count($file)-5); // strip off ".php"
    }, $this->documentFiles);
}
```

And then the instantiation test would be:

```
public function testInstantiation() {
    foreach($this->documentClasses as $class) {
        try {
            $object = new $class;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            fail("Failure to instantiate '{$class}': " + $e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

right now the test is passing because the $CWD is not the right directory and consequently it  isn't picking up any PHP files.

Is there a way to specify what the working directory should be? Ideally a way which is relative to the root of the project (and therefore abstracts the physical file system).

p.s. my project is PSR-0 compliant for what that is worth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify what the working directory should be?

You can use [`chdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php). You can also just pass a fully qualified path to `glob`:

```
glob(__DIR__ . '/*.php');
```

I don't think your solution is a good one, however. Use a [data provider](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) and return an array of instances (or class names as strings). You'll get much better error messages when you test and it won't break when/if you change directory structure.

```
<?php
class SomeExampleTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function nameProvider()
    {
        return array(
            array(new Vendor\Package\ClassName()),
            array(new Vendor\Package\ClassNameAgain()),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider nameProvider
     */
    public function testSomeMethod($obj)
    {
        // do some assertions
        $this->assertEquals('something', $obj->theMethodYouWantToTest());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, i saw the "data provider" section but thought of it as being persistent storage references not just class references. I'll take another look.

Comment: The only thing with your example ... the list is static. I'd like to have so that whenever a new class of type "ABC" is added to source that it is automatically tested for basic structural integrity.

Comment: I would consider the list being static to be a good thing. It's a test. It shouldn't be magic. It should be deliberate. Also: there's no reason you can't use a data provider that dynamically generates the class names. It's just a PHP function, you can use whatever magic you like. It just doesn't seem like a good idea to do so.

Comment: I'm easily enamoured with magic. :)  That said, you're probably right. Magic is for children.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least 2 Unittests:
Testing that all php files with their classes are found
Testing that those classes are called as expected.

Usually you are also testing the filesystem with your tests which is a bad practice. Of course, your called classes need to be tested in separeted tests too in case you haven't done that.

I don't know your class structure so I can only guess you have at least created a class for reading the files fron the given directory, a class that gets the class names (which should be a piece of psr-0 cake) and a class creating the objects from that list. That way you can mock dependencies and the access to the filesystem is reduced to a simple class that can not influence other tests when its mocked.

I suggest using the DirectoryIterator or FilesystemIterator depending on which php version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've been able to achieve the result I was looking for but I'm wondering if there might be a more savvy "PHPunit" way of doing. Please let me know if you'd do this differently.

I identified that the CWD was the `/tests/` directory. This is probably a little fragile as it could easily be run from somewhere further into the test chain but in most cases these days it's fine for me. I can then change my setUp() method to this:

```
protected function setUp() {
    $namespace = "\\path\\to\\classes\\";
    $this->documentFiles = glob('../src/path/to/classes/*.php');
    $this->documentClasses = array_map(function($file) use ($namespace) {
        if (preg_match('/.*\/(.*)\.php/',$file,$matches) === 1)
            return $namespace . $matches[1];
        else
            return null;
    }, $this->documentFiles);
}
```

As I said, it works. I'd love to think there is some more "built-in" way of doing something like this but I'm brand new to PHPunit.